# python sorting a list of words in a text file( test.txt)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython

I have a list of 5000 words in UNICODE format.
how can I sort them after appending new words into it ???

```
 a = []
    for word in text:
        if word not in dic:
            misspelled = word
            a.append(misspelled)             
            foo =misspelled
            f = open('test.txt', 'a')
            f.write(foo.encode('utf8'))
            x='\n'
            f.write(x.encode('utf8'))
            f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sort them calling .sort:

```
a.sort()
```

You should also open the file once and use `with` to open your files:

```
with  open('test.txt', 'w') as f:      
    for word in text:
        if word not in dic:
            misspelled = word
            a.append(misspelled)
            foo = misspelled
            ..........
    a.sort() # sort
    for word in a:
        f.write("{}\n".format(word))
```

Comment: I did but when I open the text file  I see no change and the new words are inserted to the last line of the list @padraic

Comment: @BamoNabaz, that is what `a` does, it appends to a file

Comment: I read the OP's code and yours, the OP seems to have an additional `f.write(x.encode('utf8'))`. Is it even required?

Comment: @BhargavRao . You could just write the Unicode but the op is encoding to str. I am not overly sure where the data is coming from or indeed whether the file even has content or not. If the op wants they can add an encode. The appending and writing is confusing

Comment: The question is tagged with both 2 and 3, which makes it even more ambiguous :)

Comment: @BhargavRao. Well it will be a mystery for the morning time to crash here ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize `a` with the current list of words, then just spend to it as you go, like you are, and then sort `a` before writing it to the file.

```
f = file("test.txt", "r")
a = f.readlines()
. . . # Looping to find misspelled words, spending to a
f = file("test.txt", "w")
f.write("\n".join(sorted(a)).encode("utf-8")
f.close()
```